# React Native Send 2 values on onPress event then pass to another screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

This is my JSON file

```
{
    "name": "Thịt bò",
    "noed": 5
},
{
    "name": "Thịt heo",
    "noed": 3
}
```

I get them to Flatlist

```
   <FlatList
      data={cats}
      keyExtractor={item => item.name}
      renderItem={({item})=>(
          <View>
              <Text style={styles.catsItem} onPress={() => this.changeTextInput(item.name)}>{item.name} {item.noed}</Text>
          </View>
      )}
/>
```

But I want to send 2 values are `item.name` and `item.noed` to TextInput then send them to another screen

```
changeTextInput(item){
        this.setState({name: item});
    };
```

But I don't know how to send `item.noed` to TextInput and how to send them to another screen.
I'm quite new, so please help me.

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation`?

Comment: You basically want to store the input value the user types to the component state. Look at the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput `onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}`. To debug, log the state in your render to see if it's really saved to your state ` render() { console.log(this.state); return <Flatlist.... `

And finally, you want to pass that same state as props to your next screen.
if your using react-navigation from expo, something like this will do:
`this.props.navigation.navigate("MyNextScreen", { userInput: this.state });`

Answer (score 1):

Use react-navigation npm package to redirect from one screen to another screen you can also pass values

There are two pieces to this:

Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second    parameter to the navigation.navigate function:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate
('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })




onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', 
    { itemId: 86, otherParam: 'anything you want here', })};
```

Read the params in your screen component:

```
this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue)
```

For more information please read the following document

[React Navigation Link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)