# How to get data from page that I sent data?

Tags: react-native

*I pass data from Page1 to Page2 and when I press button in Page2, I want to pass data to Page1.*

**I send to Page2 like this:**

```
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Page2', { info: 'Test' })}>

        </TouchableOpacity>
```

**I take data in Page2**

```
 state= {
            inPage2: this.props.navigation.state.params.info,
        }
```

**I send from Page2 :**

```
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Page1', { info2: 'Test2' })}>

        </TouchableOpacity>
```

*and I take from page1 like in page2. but it gives undefined. How can I fix this*

Comment: it's `this.props.navigation.getParam('info'); // not Info`

Comment: I made mistake when I write here. I edited post.  But this is not work for me. I can pass data to Page2 from Page1. How I can pass data to Page1 from Page2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Send 2 values on onPress event then pass to another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226091/react-native-send-2-values-on-onpress-event-then-pass-to-another-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you access your params in Page2:

```
const info = this.props.navigation.getParam('info');
```